# How to detect one user is logged in multiple Lync client using UCMA or Lync SDK?

Tags: ucma, lync-client-sdk

I want to know which user is logged in multiple Lync client in different machines.
So how should I get to know and which SDK will gives this details?

Answer (score 1):

With either UCMA or Lync Client SDK you can determine if one or more clients are logged in using presence [subscription](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn465955.aspx).  This will give you a simple "there is a endpoint running somewhere or not", but that's not what you are asking for.

As far as I know, there is no way to do what you want with UCMA or the Lync Client SDK.

You can do it with the [Lync Server SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn454964.aspx), but it will take some work.  You can do with either a MSPL script (limited) or MSPL/C# proxy application (more options) that [filters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn439115.aspx) for [REGISTER](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261) requests/responses.

From the register request you can determine if it's a register (coming online), unregister (going offline) or re-registration (replacing existing registration) by the expires header / contact uri expires parameter (0 == unregister).

You can determine the user type by the user-agent header, mainly between Lync Client (e.g. "UCCAPI/15.0.4771.1000 OC/15.0.4771.1001 (Skype for Business)"), Lync Phone, UCMA endpoint (e.g. RTCC/5.0.0.0 Xxxx).

You also need to handle registration timeout and re-registration.

With this knowledge you have a running knowledge of what user agents are running for the users you wish to track and do with what you wish.

So if you really want to do this, I would as a prerequisite to starting:

- Get familiar with [sip messaging](http://www.voipmechanic.com/sip-call-example.htm).
- Play around with building / running the examples in the Lync Server SDK.

Answer (score 0):

MSPL will be a solution, but that will ask you some work like "Shane Powell" said.

The most easy way will be to use Powershell...

I use for my part "Get-CsConnections" from [ehloworld](http://www.ehloworld.com/269).

Is a powershell script who it will shows you all the details of connection about any users.